# iOS Pattern with Objective C example to prevent concurrent calls to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, concurrency

I am looking for the best pattern to adopt to ensure a method is prevented from running concurrently.  An example in objective C would be ideal.

Is it best to use a lock inside the call wrapped around an if statement or an NSOperationQueue and allow only 1 concurrent operation and check the queue for items before adding new ones to the queue.  Or should I be looking at something completely different?

The objective is to allow the method to be called on an object and for subsequent calls to be ignored if it is already running.

Comment: I am curious what a good use case is for that scenario. I can think of buttons that trigger some action and shouldn't trigger again, but then, disabling them would be the better choice.

Comment: you can try `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selName:) withObject:someObj waitUntilDone:YES];` and `return;` from the selName funtion e.g.: `- (void)selName:(id)someObj { //do stuff  return; }`

Comment: Hi Eiko, either for long running or async operations that can be called from multiple places or from multiple threads.  For example, an async server call that I don't want to make again if it is already in flight.  There could be several triggers for this method, pull to refresh, a button, a heartbeat timer, a push notification, etc. and would have to disable them all or I could change the behaviour of the method to not allow concurrency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update.** Thanks Rob for pointing out the flaw in the original code. Basically by using `dispatch_sync` there's no need to set the flag, as anyhow there will be only one block executed at any point in time. Replacing it with `dispatch_async` will allow multiple executions, however you loose the synchronous behaviour that you might need in your application.

A better approach, that doesn't require dispatch queues, and is faster and more robust, is to use atomic operations to update your flag:

```
// nonatomic is not important here, as we'll assure atomicity with better tools
@property(nonatomic) int runningImportantOperation;

- (void)doSomething {
    // atomic check of the flag, if the flag is already set, then exit
    if (OSAtomicTestAndSet(0, &runningImportantOperation)) { return; }

    // execute the actual code
    [self doTheActualStuff];

    // reset the flag
    OSAtomicTestAndClear(0, &runningImportantOperation);
}
```

---

### Original answer

You can use a serial dispatch queue that will make sure that there will be no concurrent calls to your method, along with a flag set on the queue that tells if the method is running or not. Something like below:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
       // check if we set the flag, if we did it, exit
       if (dispatch_get_specific(_cmd)) { return; }

       // set the flag; _cmd is used here only to make sure we have a unique value
       dispatch_queue_set_specific(myQueue,_cmd,@YES,NULL);

       // execute the actual code
       [self doTheActualStuff];

       // reset the flag
       dispatch_queue_set_specific(myQueue,_cmd,NULL,NULL);
    });
}
```

Comment: If `myQueue` is serial, then how would the flag ever be set when tested? `dispatch_sync` would block until the previous calls complete (so the call wouldn't be ignored; `doSomething` would just hang). If `myQueue` is concurrent, then isn't there's a race condition between `dispatch_get_specific` and `dispatch_queue_set_specific`?

Comment: OSAtomicTestAndClear is deprecated in iOS 10.0 for those developing for it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with a straight serial dispatch queue is it won't meet your objective "to allow the method to be called on an object *and for subsequent calls to be ignored if it is already running*."

A couple techniques you could consider:

**1. dispatch_semaphore**

Consider using `dispatch_semaphore`, described here [using dispatch_sync as a mutex lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326131/using-dispatch-sync-as-a-mutex-lock).

This is what it would look like:

```
// create a semaphore, a static object
static dispatch_semaphore_t sema; // The semaphore
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    // Initialize with count=1 (this is executed only once):
    sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
});
```

Then your operation function would test the semaphore

```
- (void) myOperation
{
 // Try to decrement the semaphore. This succeeds if the count is still 1
 // (meaning that this code is not already executing), and fails if the 
 // current count is 0 (meaning that this code is executing):
 if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) 
 {
    // Success, semaphore count is now 0.

    // Do your stuff...your critical non-concurrent code goes here
    .
    .
    .

    // Increment the semaphore count (from 0 to 1), so that the next call
    // to myOperation will start a new operation:
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
  }
}
```

**2. NSOperationQueue**

Otherwise, `NSOperationQueue` is a reasonable technique.  An `NSOperationQueue` has a property called `operations`, which provides a means for identifying currently running or queued operations.

You can create a wrapper class holding the operation queue:

```
@interface MyServiceQueue : NSObject
{
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue; // operation queue
}

@property (nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

- (void) startMyOperation;           // this will start your task
```

And implementation

```
@implementation MyServiceQueue

// create the operationQueue on demand
- (NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue
{
    if (operationQueue == nil)
    {
        operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];          // concurrent queue
    }
    return (operationQueue);
}

// this will start your NSOperation subclass, called MyOperation here
- (void) startMyOperation
{

    // discard if other MyOperations already in queue.
    // You could also just check the count of operations if you only
    // have one type that could be in your queue.  This code presumes
    // you might mix other types of tasks in the queue so is doing
    // the isKindOfClass check

    for (NSOperation *op in self.operationQueue.operations)
    {
        if ([op isKindOfClass:[MyOperation class]])
            return;
    }

    // create a MyOperation and add it to the queue
    MyOperation *myOperation = [[MyOperation alloc] init];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:myOperation];
}
```

Comment: I believe this only works if `startMyOperation` is restricted to a serial queue (for example if it is required to be called on `mainQueue`). Otherwise, there's a race condition between checking the queue and adding to the queue. That may be an ok restriction for this problem, but is important to note.

Comment: I would definitely go with the linked question. This is exactly what a semaphore is intended to solve.

Comment: @Rob Napier, good point.  This would be less likely to occur if the test were just { if self.operationQueue.operations.count > 0 }, but agree that semaphore is much tighter.  I've edited my answer putting this first!